# Dropzone.js - to call or use 2 init function

Tags: dropzone.js

I am using dropzone.js for my project.
Is it possible to use or to call two(2) "init: function" there?

Thanks for helping .

I have this

```
    Dropzone.options.filedrop = {
       maxFilesize: 4096,
       init: function () {
           this.on("complete", function (file) {
               doSomething();
          });
       }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can do it like this:

```
Dropzone.options.filedrop = {
    maxFilesize: 4096,
    init: function () {
        this.on("complete", function (file) {
            doSomething();
        }),
        this.on('sending', function () {
            doSomethingElse();
        })
    }
};
```